# If $x$ and $y$ are indistinguishable from $a$, then $(x, y)$ is indistinguishable from $(a, a)$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be some set with a topology $T$, and $x,y\in X$ indistinguishable from $a$, in the sense that any neighborhood of $a$ contains $x$ and $y$. I'd like to prove that in the product topology on $X^2$, $(x, y)$ is in the same sense indistinguishable from $(a, a)$.

I thought I could start something like this: let $S$ be the set of neighborhoods of $(a, a)$ in $T^2$ (by which I mean the product topology) which contain $(x, y)$. $S$ contains the products of neighborhoods of $a$, and $S$ is closed under unions and finite intersections... but I'm not quite sure where that's going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any neighborhood of $(a,a)$ in $X \times X$ contains an open neighborhood of $(a,a)$ of the form $U \times V$ where $U$ and $V$ are open in $X$. Therefore, if $(a,a) \in U \times V$, then $a \in U$ and $a \in V$ so $x,y \in U$ and $x,y \in V$, so in fact $$(x,x),(x,y),(y,y) \in U \times V$$
So it's not disguishable.

Comment: When you say "contains an open set" on the first line, do you mean "contains a neighborhood"? Otherwise, how do you justify $(a, a)\in U\times V$?

Comment: Yes, sorry! Fixed.

Comment: Can that statement be generalized? If $T$ is a topology generated by some family of sets $F$, then does any neighborhood of $x$ in $T$ contain a set containing $x$ which is in $F$?

Comment: @Jack: Depends on what you mean by *generated by*. If $F$ is a base for $T$, the answer is *yes*; if $F$ is only a subbase for $T$, the answer is *no* in general.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Interesting. Looks like I've been mistaken this whole time about what the definition of the product topology is, I thought it was the smallest topology containing the cartesian products of opens in the factor topologies.

Comment: @Jack: It is, in the case of products of finitely many spaces. The family of products of open sets is a base for it.